# No rule to make target ***

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, target

I am currently trying to build Face Tracker (by Jason Saragih) with "make" in my Windows 7 x64, but all I'm getting is: "No rule to make target src/lib/IO.o, needed by bin/face_tracker".

Does anyone have any idea of what is happening, please?

This is the makefile (also available in Jason Saragih's page):

```
# Paths
OPENCV_PATH=/OpenCV246/

# Programs
CC=
CXX=g++

# Flags
ARCH_FLAGS=-arch x86_64
CFLAGS=-Wextra -Wall -pedantic-errors $(ARCH_FLAGS) -O3
LDFLAGS=$(ARCH_FLAGS)
DEFINES=
INCLUDES=-I$(OPENCV_PATH)/include -Iinclude/
LIBRARIES=-L$(OPENCV_PATH)/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_objdetect

# Files which require compiling
SOURCE_FILES=\
    src/lib/IO.cc\
    src/lib/PDM.cc\
    src/lib/Patch.cc\
    src/lib/CLM.cc\
    src/lib/FDet.cc\
    src/lib/PAW.cc\
    src/lib/FCheck.cc\
    src/lib/Tracker.cc

# Source files which contain a int main(..) function
SOURCE_FILES_WITH_MAIN=src/exe/face_tracker.cc

# End Configuration
SOURCE_OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(SOURCE_FILES))

ALL_OBJECTS=\
    $(SOURCE_OBJECTS) \
    $(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(SOURCE_FILES_WITH_MAIN))

DEPENDENCY_FILES=\
    $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$(ALL_OBJECTS)) 

all: bin/face_tracker

%.o: %.cc Makefile
    @# Make dependecy file
    $(CXX) -MM -MT $@ -MF $(patsubst %.cc,%.d,$<) $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES) $<
    @# Compile
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES) -c -o $@ $< 

-include $(DEPENDENCY_FILES)

bin/face_tracker: $(ALL_OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBRARIES) -o $@ $(ALL_OBJECTS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @echo "Cleaning"
    @for pattern in '*~' '*.o' '*.d' ; do \
        find . -name "$$pattern" | xargs rm ; \
    done
```

Thanks, 
Fabio

Comment: There are many different version of the make command that all work a little different.  This looks like a GNU make makefile.  Check which version of make you are using.  If it is the plain windows make, that is not going to work.

Comment: That error Fabio quoted looks like an error from GNU make to me.  However there are a ton of things that could be causing problems on Windows.  I'm assuming you're using GCC to compile it.  I'm also assuming you're invoking make from the directory containing the makefile, and that the file src/lib/IO.cc actually does exist.  If so you should run `make -d` and look at the output (there's a lot of it).  I'm not familiar with the MinGW environment unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, guys! In fact, it was a GNU make. Now I'm trying to run it in Ubuntu and I'm getting the following output: "Unrecognized command line option: -arch" and "x86_64: No such file or directory". Do you know what's going on now?

Comment: The argument -arch is not recognized by the compiler. The argument 'x86_64' is being seen as a filename, not as a modifier to -arch. It appears the original make may have been written to target a 64-bit machine from a 32-bit host. Hope this helps.